# Sailsjs 0.12 - Custom method for all models

Tags: sails.js

I am trying to add Laravel-like Mass Assign to my Sails 0.12 application.

So far I have done:

Add method `secureUpdate` to `config\models.js`:

```
console.log(this);

var self = this;
var modelName = self.adapter.identity.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + self.adapter.identity.slice(1);
```

I am trying to get the calling model name, just like in `seed` method in this gist(for seeding data): https://gist.github.com/juanpasolano/5c7596d8629eeeb8debd#file-config-models-js

But the value of `this` is diffirent, with no adapter object(undefined)

I do not understand why the value of `this` is not the same. Could you help me out?

Comment: Could you show the whole method definition ?

Comment: @HamzaFatmi This is the whole method for now. I can not continue because I can not get the model name, due to `undefined` adapter object

Comment: are you defining the method with an arrow function ?

Comment: Jesus, you are correct. If you can move above comment to an answer, I will upvote it. Thanks alot.

Comment: no problem , glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write the answer here just for others who may have the same problem in the future :

The `this` is `undefined` because you are defining the **method** as an arrow function, you have to use a **function expression**, from MDN :

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and **does not have its own this**, arguments, super, or new.target. These function expressions are best suited for **non-method** functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.